# jQuery.next() - Why does it skip the contains condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this list that I'm doing 
`.nextUntil(':contains("2010")')` on. When calling `.next()` on the variable set by `.nextUntil()`, apparently jQuery skips the initial `:contains()` condition.

Why is this happening? Is it a bug or am I missing something?

```
<nav class="timeLineNav">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected is-loaded"><a href="#year2014">2014</a></li>
        <li class="is-loaded"><a href="#year2013">2013</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#year2012">2012</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#year2011">2011</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#year2010">2010</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And here's the JavaScript code:

```
var list = $('.timeLineNav ul li');

var nextUntil = list.nextUntil(':contains("2010")');
nextUntil.each(function (n, v) {
    $('#length').append('<li>' + $(v).text() + ' ' + '</li>');
});

var next = nextUntil.next();

next.each(function (n, v) {
    $('#nextLength').append('<li>' + $(v).text() + ' ' + '</li>');
});
```

Here is a fiddle with a complete example http://jsfiddle.net/klingan/bwmx6Lbr/

Comment: I want to say it's because the selector used to create `list` doesn't automatically include freshly-added elements, but I'm not certain.

Comment: But nothing is dynamically added to that list?

Comment: Oh, never mind, then. Are you sure that the `var next = nextUntil.next()` is correct? It seems like all that is doing is popping the first element out of the jQuery object...

Comment: That's just from the fiddle, to demonstrate how the lists look after the `nextUntil()` and `next()`

Comment: why can't you `$('ul').children('li')` ?

Comment: Hmm, everything works as it should. `next` takes a sibling for *each* element of the matching set resulting in 17 found elements. What are you trying to achive?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I think Chris want to display all year? is that right? the problem now is .next() is applied to each of the $nextUntil, instead of adding the extra li at the end.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko has a point; it looks like you're lopping off the last element in the first operation, then moving the whole list forward by one in the second.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja and Yury, you are correct; `next()` moves every element of the list forward by one. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output in the jsfiddle is as expected.
With the `var nextUntil = list.nextUntil(':contains("2010")');` the variable `nextUntil` has the "collection" `{2013, 2012, 2011}`

Then for each items in this collection you print the next li which is:

```
for 2013 --> 2012,
2012 --> 2011,
2011 --> 2010.
```

Hence the second output on the jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks, the fact that it iterates over each element in the list makes perfect sense when you think about it. Thanks for a short and concise answer!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/bzehqy16/3/

I think this is what you want, instead of proforming next() at each of the jQuery objects you use .add() and find the .last() of the objects

```js
var list = $('.timeLineNav ul li');

var nextUntil = list.nextUntil(':contains("60-tal")');
nextUntil.each(function(n, v) {
    $('#length').append('<li>' + $(v).text() + ' ' + '</li>');
});

var next = nextUntil.add(nextUntil.last());

next.each(function(n, v) {
    $('#nextLength').append('<li>' + $(v).text() + ' ' + '</li>');
});
```

```css
body{
    background-color:lightgrey;
}

ul.length li{
    display:inline;
    padding:100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="timeLineNav">
  <ul>
    <li class="selected is-loaded"><a href="#year2014">2014</a></li>
    <li class="is-loaded"><a href="#year2013">2013</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year2012">2012</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year2011">2011</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year2010">2010</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year2009">2009</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year2008">2008</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year2007">2007</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year2006">2006</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year2005">2005</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year2004">2004</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year2003">2003</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year2002">2002</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year2001">2001</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year2000">2000</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year90-tal">90-tal</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year80-tal">80-tal</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year70-tal">70-tal</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#year60-tal">60-tal</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<ul class="length" id="length"></ul>
<ul style="color:red;" class="length" id="nextLength"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are performing `.nextUnil()` on a list, try:

```
var item = $('.timeLineNav ul li').first();
var nextUntil = item.nextUntil(':contains("2011")');
// nextUntil should now have the li element next to <a href="#year2011">2011</a>
```

Comment: This didn't actually change anything about the output.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm understanding, you're expecting `nextUntil` to select up to and including 2010?

The `nextUntil` is actually working as designed and is nothing to do with your `:contains()` condition.

I have added code to your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwmx6Lbr/1/) to show this, but here's the added code:

```js
var current = $('#start').nextUntil('.current');
var currentNext = $('#start').nextUntil('.current').next();

$('#result').html('nextUntil = ' + current.text() + '<br />nextUntil + next = ' + currentNext.text());
```

```css
#result {
    background:#eee;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:500px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="start">Start</span><br />
<span>1</span><br />
<span>2</span><br />
<span class="current">3</span><br />
<span>4</span><br />
<span>5</span><br />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue your experiencing is that both nextUntil and next doesn't work on the list. They both search the DOM tree.

Comment: Yes, I got that from the selected answer. Thanks for your time :)